# How can i add audio at specific Frame in FFmpeg?

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, video

I have audio that i am adding (without Re-encode) in mute video file, in starting i have intro which has no sound and i want to add audio file after that time/frame , after searching so hard i only found this command useful, `ffmpeg -y -i file.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:05 - i file.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 out.mp4`

it does the job but the problem is , its not precise , it is kind of mismatch because audio is supposed to be starting at 4.840 seconds & i cannot do it with this command, i want audio to be inserted at Fixed Frame, please suggest me any command to resolve issue :(

Thanks

I tried on Mkvtoolnix,Reddit, various command site etc .

Comment: Have you tried `-itsoffset 4.840`?

Comment: yes tried , Not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a silent segment using `anullsrc` for the duration of the offset. Then, use `concat` filter to append the wave file to it. If the wave file is shorter than the remaining video, add another silent segment in the the concat filter. You can then specify this concatenated audio in the second `-map`.